# how to edit and use the template given on visual studio 2012 for asp.mvc 4 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have been trying  to develop a web application based in asp.net mvc4 by using visual studio 2012. I want use the template already provided by visual studio by adding images which will be slide but I coudn't find how to do that.

second, I have registration databse table created in sql express 2012,
Create Table Registration
(
RegID int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,
FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
Username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
passeword varchar(50)NOT NULL,
Gender varchar(10),
Home_Address varchar(100),
Office_Address varchar(100), 
City varchar(25), 
State varchar(25), 
Zip varchar(25), 
Contact_No int , 
Email varchar(25)
);
I need to modify the registartion form already availabele by deafult to have the information available in registartion data base table,  how i have to modify it to have those fields and store database?

Comment: This is the whole point of the starting apps... to give you a base on which to customize your own things.  :)  You are going in the right direction.  It is not as clear which kinds of help you are asking for.  If you want to change the look, you will need to change the Site.css.  If you want to change the registration, you will need to add your database connections.  Can you change your question to be more specific about which steps you want help with first?

Comment: thank you jennifer, I have edit it

Comment: hi jennefier, I have been trying to connect the defualt registration form availabe with registarion table I have created in sql serever express. but I am getting error. what would you suggest me to connect the registartion form available by deafult with regesrtion table avialbe in sql server

Comment: Is the correct connection string in your web.config file for your instance of SQL Server Express?  Do you have anything in your connectionStrings section of the web.config?

Comment: by using Entity framework and by changing connect string. It is connected with database and atomatically add those table available by defuault in to my database.

[dbo].[System_Users]

[dbo].[UserProfile]

[dbo].[webpages_Membership]

[dbo].[webpages_OAuthMembership]

[dbo].[webpages_Roles]

[dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles]

When I checked by putting some data in registor form it does not save on my registration database table.wich I created in sql express. how can I solve this issue?